# pipe in shell with redirection

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe, io-redirection

My understanding is that a pipe in shell like `a | b` redirects `b`'s stdin to `a`'s stdout. However, I tried `ls | less < somefile`, the behavior is very strange. `less` shows the output of `ls` concatenated by the content of `somefile`.

Could someone explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is not quite correct. In `a | b` the stdout output of process `a` connected through a pipe to **stdin** of process `b`. The problem with your code is that with an additional redirection from `somefile` to process `b` you will use two different methods at the same time to connect to stdin of process `b`. Don't do that! The question is; what do you try to achieve (with such a construct) in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what shell are you using. From the behaviour you are describing it's likely `zsh`. If you have a look in its man page you would notice how redirections are handled.

> Note that a pipe is an implicit redirection; thus
>
> ```
>   cat bar | sort <foo
> ```
>
> is equivalent to `cat bar foo | sort` (note the order of the inputs).

Otherwise, regular behaviour e.g., that one of `bash` is that each redirection replaces the previous redirection for that file descriptor.

`zsh` man page continues:

> If the MULTIOS option is unset, each redirection replaces the previous redirection for that file descriptor.  However, all files
>   redirected to are actually opened, so
>
> ```
>   echo foo > bar > baz
> ```
>
> when MULTIOS is unset will truncate bar, and write `foo' into baz.

Answer (score 1):

because you are taking input of less from somefile.

it works like this

1 -> execute ls , as you have used pipe , it will pipe stdout to stdin of next command : this is what you are telling

2 -> it will look second command.. it is less < somefile

as soon as it sees **'<' redirection it will change stdin again to the file... Hence your previous change because of '|' is getting lost.**

well, you can say it like this :
less have taken input from file , it has nothing to do with ls's output.